# Is it a security risk to allow the following HTML elements (e.g. code, pre)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, wysihtml5

I'm using the following plugin: https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/

This is how I'm sanitizing my input/outputs in my Rails app:

**post.rb:**

```
  protected

  def clean_input
    self.content = sanitize(self.content, :tags => %w(b i u br p span blockquote pre code), :attributes => %w(id class style))
  end
```

**posts/show.html.rb:**

```
  <p><%= sanitize @post.content, :tags => %w(b i u p span br blockquote pre code), :attributes => %w(id class style) %></p>
```

This parser rules for **wysihtml5** (of course, the editor is allowing tags like b, i, etc. as default):

**shared/editor_toolbar:**

```
  parserRules: {
      classes: {
        "ruby": 1,
        "variable": 1,
        "string": 1
      },
      tags: {
        span: {},
        code: {},
        pre: {}
      }
    },
```

So, right now the user can input and the app can output something like this:

```
  <pre class="ruby">
   <code>
    <span class="variable">
    $(</span><span class="string">'.wysihtml5'</span>).wysihtml5({<span class=
    "string">'stylesheets'</span>: false});
   </code>
  </pre>
```

(The user can switch from visual and html view)

I hope this is not a stupid question (I'm not very familiar with security), but is this relatively safe or dangerous? If so, how to prevent it?

Answer (score 3):

I really don't know about Ruby, but in PHP you can allow tags like that and from what I've experimented, it's **NOT** secure at all... The reason why is because attributes on these authorized tags are not sanitised so any user could input a very gentle and inoffensive `<span></span>` tag but adding this to it :

`<span onmouseover="hack_the_whole_fucking_website();">contenthere</span>`

This way, the JavaScript will be executed when a user move his mouse over it ! From there I guess an hacked could steal user's cookies + steal Session cookie + hijack users Sessions + maybe hijack an admin session and then explode your website. It's an open door for hackers.

**The solution** I use for this is BBcode tags. They are kind of "substitutes" for existing HTML tags. Some examples :

- `<i>` = `[i]`
- `<img src="#">` = `[img=#]`
- `<a href="#">text</a>` = `[url=#]text[/url]`
- ...

The output of the editor should be in this format so you can run a sanitizing script that properly delete all real HTML tags. And then when it's time to output this data to the user, you replace these replacement tags by the real HTML tag using some regular expressions. :)

Comment: I think this line: `:attributes => %w(id class style)` is telling the app that those are the only HTML attributes allowed. So `onmouseover` won't be allowed.

Comment: Ohhh I haven't looked, if it's actually true, Ruby is better that PHP on this point lol And maybe it's finally secure but... personally speaking, i would still feel insecure to have user-generated HTML in my database so I would still use BBcode tags, just to be sure :)

Comment: Same issue with BBCode: `[img=javascript:…]`. Validation doesn’t stop at HTML level.

Comment: Absolutely true, but this can be filtered easily with regular expressions by detecting this `javascript:` beginning part of the URL part.